# Codeigniter Global Array Declaration

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a sequence of number like follows

1  ->  25,
2  -> 60,
3  -> 80,
4  -> 100 
and so on

which means that if input is 1 output will be 25 and so on...I need to store it in global array.I would like to use it in multiple pages also.In codeigniter where i can declare a global array and store all these?

I am trying like as follows in constants.php

`$CONFIDENCEVALUE = array();
$CONFIDENCEVALUE[] = array('1'=>25,'2'=>'60','3'=>80,'4'=>100);`

If it is correct how can access these array value in required pages.Help me please.I am not an expert with codeignitor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I were you I'd look at adding a custom config file (see https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html).

So in eg. `application/config/confidencevalue.php` add the following

```
$CONFIDENCEVALUE = array('1'=>25,'2'=>'60','3'=>80,'4'=>100);
$config['confidencevalue'] = $CONFIDENCEVALUE;
```

Add the config file to your `application/config/autoload.php`  and you'll then be able to access your array through the config class using `$this->config->item('1', 'confidencevalue');` (replacing the 1 for the value you're looking for).

Comment: Now how do I add another value to this array dynamically? and delete one with key 2?

Answer (score 0):

Store the array in a session variable:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('cvarray', $CONFIDENCEVALUE);
```

To access the array later:

```
$this->session->userdata('cvarray');
```

CodeIgniter [Session Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by adding a function to a helper file that you make available globally.

I have a helper file application/helpers/main_helper.php in which I load a number of generic, common functions which are used throughout my application.

If you add the following function to the main_helper file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Function to retrieve Static Variables used Globally
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function get_var($var = 'CONFIDENCEVALUE', $KEY = NULL) {
    $r = false;
    switch ($var) {
        case 'CONFIDENCEVALUE':
            $r = array('1'=>25,'2'=>'60','3'=>80,'4'=>100);
            if($KEY !== NULL) $r = $r[$KEY];
            break;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

This file is auto-loaded by editing the file application/config/autoload.php and editing the line:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('main_helper');
```

Whenever this array (or a value from the array) is needed, call the function instead. eg.:

```
$CONFIDENCE = get_var('CONFIDENCEVALUE', 2);
```

If you include the $KEY when calling get_var(), then only the value is returned, otherwise the whole array is returned.

To make additional variables available, just add them to the switch and call them as needed.
Feedback welcome :).